# How can I transfer the commit history of a repository to another repository?

Tags: git, repository, commit, git-commit

I've spent a few months working on a project.  It broke, I started a new project and just transfered the files, but I would like to transfer just the commit history into the new repository/project?  I am a little familiar with git.  What command line codes would I need to only transfer the commit history?

Answer (score 3):

Basically you want to add a new remote, so in the old project you just need to add a new remote:

```
$ git remote add origin git@remote-path/project.git
```

then run:

```
$ git remote -v
```

and you should have two remotes.

If you have the error:

```
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

just use other name for remote:

```
$ git remote add new-origin git@remote-path/project.git
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. Simply:

1. Go to project directory

   ```
   cd ProjectAcceptingCommitMessages
   ```
2. Add project with commit history to current repository

   ```
   git remote add projectB /home/you/projectB
   git fetch projectB
   ```
3. Then merge the two together, therefore giving you the commit history

   ```
   git merge projectB/master
   ```